# Would it be wrong if you gave a non-believer money (or food) only if he would convert to islam?

Tags: non-muslim, muslim-practices

I've encountered a lot of beggars in my life, some were non-believer, some believers.

I gave money to the believers and a couple of times to non-believers too, soon to realize that they (non-believers) spent it on alcohol and such. Then I started to to think that I should have bought food for them instead just to avoid that they'd sin because of me.

> Now I've come to realize wouldn't it be better that I should tell the beggar to convert to islam otherwise I won't do it. Note that I see the beggar almost every week if I go grocery shopping. So I can check him if he keeps his end of the promise by simple things as clothes, no breath that smells like alcohol, etc.
>
> Would this act be allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Verse (2:256)](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(2:256:1))

> There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion....

[Verse (60:8)](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(60:8:7))

> Allah does not forbid you from those who do not fight you because of
>   religion and do not expel you from your homes - from being righteous
>   toward them and acting justly toward them. Indeed, Allah loves those
>   who act justly.

[Verse (60:9)](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(60:9:1))

> Allah only forbids you from those who fight you because of religion
>   and expel you from your homes and aid in your expulsion - [forbids]
>   that you make allies of them. And whoever makes allies of them, then
>   it is those who are the wrongdoers.

It's clear from above verses that we need to be just with those who don't fight us because of religion.

Many scholars agreed that even we can give Zakat to non-muslims (needy people).

Just watch this 1 minute video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cmVhm3mCqM

When we are donating, people are agree to listen, so we can do the DAWAH with hiqmah.

**Story of Ibrahim (ASW) and Old man (Non-believer)**

Ibrahim (ASW) used to invite guest every day,  one morning an old man appeared on a camel. Hazrat Ibrahim was happy. He invited the old man to his home to eat with him The old man accepted the invitation.

In the house they set to eat. Hazrat Ibrahim recited “Bismillah” before taking the food, but the old man did not say anything. Hazrat Ibrahim asked why he did not remember Allah before taking his meal. Was not Allah our Creator, our Nourisher and our Master? Was it not proper to remember Him before partaking of the food provided by Him?

The old man said that it was not the custom in his religion. Hazrat Ibrahim asked him what his religion was. He said that he was one of those who worship fire.

Hazrat Ibrahim was very much annoyed and turned the old man out.

As soon as the old man went away, the angel Jibrail came to Hazrat Ibrahim, from Allah. Jibrail told Hazrat Ibrahim that Allah had been feeding this unbeliever person for seventy years. Could not Hazrat Ibrahim tolerate him for even one meal! Hazrat Ibrahim felt very sorry for this. He immediately ran after the old man. Finally he reached him and persuaded him to return to his house to have food together. He finally succeeded in getting the old man to his home.

Comment: Everything I'd do is just, so the act is allowed?

Comment: Just added the story of Ibrahim (asw) and old man, hope it will help to understand

Comment: What is the link between your story and my question? Is it used for motivation for me that I one day will succeed to convert that man or has it to do with the fact that I need to let him believe in his own religion?